# Using bootstrap with git

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how git works. I want to use bootstrap as a starting point for all my websites (each project as its own repo). I'd like to pull in bootstrap and update when necessary, but I don't want everything in the bootstrap repo, just the css and js files.

It seems I must do the following:

1. Create repo.
2. Submodule bootstrap.
3. Create aliases to the specific files I want.
4. Update the submodule when necessary.

Is this really the only option? Is it not possible to pull just the subfolders I want from a specific repo and update them manually? Also, if my solution is the only way, shouldn't I add the submodule folder to my gitignore file?

Answer (score 5):

While your steps sound reasonable, I suggest not to do that.

Reasons:

1. Submodule is a bit complex for beginner. Better not to use it for real project.
2. You should have more libs to manage other than Bootstrap, if your site is not very simple and static. These should be not the jobs of GIT to manage them, otherwise you'll be too busy.

In my opinion, the better use case of sub module is to manage key libs dependency but not a bunch of packages for a site or an app.

My recommendations:

1. Use GIT to manage your own code only.
2. For external libs:

   1. Use package management tool of your framework/language, like Gemfile for Rails, npm for Node.
   2. If no such tool available, I prefer to create a script to pull appropriate version of libs from Github, and then keep this script in version control.
   3. If making script is still troublesome, just write a plain text file to record the version of libs you use, and keep this file version controlled. When upgrading needed, upgrade the necessary ones manually. Though this looks like a bit more work, I think it's still much simpler than sub module.

Comment: It's worth noting that Twitter's [Bower](http://twitter.github.io/bower) is *great* for managing Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, I will look into bower, I've noticed it but I didn't want to install a million shell scripts and forget about what I've downloaded, why, and how I'm using them. And I likely will have other libs to manage, I was just starting with bootstrap, but bower may be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to use GIT to manage a 'real' project, I recommend learning how GIT works first and to practice using GIT with some trivial content (e.g. simple text files) that don't require much effort to create and cost nothing to destroy!

I'd suggest first reading Tom Preston-Werner's [GIT Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html)

Then, you may want to watch the PeepCode [GIT tutorial](https://peepcode.com/products/git) or TekPub [Mastering GIT](http://tekpub.com/productions/git) tutorial videos.

And don't forget to practice, practice, practice! GIT is insanely powerful but with that power comes some complexity. Spent time learning GIT with unimportant simple text files to start with - it'll save you a lot of headache later.

Comment: I believe that there are hundreds of free nice tutorials and guides for git like the book: [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book). I see no point to pay for learning Git really.

Comment: @pigueiras: That's your choice, but in my experience, learning from good screencasts is often faster and more valuable than learning from books (free or otherwise). Not everything in the world HAS to be free to be good.

Comment: I should clarify, I understand how git works (though I'm not pretending to have mastered it or be fluent) & have practiced on small files. I do appreciate your links for a better understanding on git, and have read **Pro Git**. My question is more about the ability to do a specific thing: to pull _certain_ files/folders from a repo into my own repos. Submodule IS tricky but I definitely don't want to clone the full repo nor download a zip repeatedly. It may be that what I want to do may not be as useful as I think. I just had an idea about how I could better incorporate git into my workflow.

Comment: Ahhh. I think what you want then is how to use Git "cherry-picking": http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the solution I want is in fact [Bower](http://bower.io). Thanks, [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109908/david-blayney).